What is the benefit of transfers with the TransferWithSeedParams?
Using the web3.js library, when doing a transfer of Sol with the SystemProgram.transfer function, what is the benefit of using the TransferWithSeedParams as opposed to the regular TransferParams? I realize that the former is meant for transferring SOL between a base account and a derived one, but couldn't this be achieved with the regular TransferParams? (Reference).

I misunderstood the purpose of Transfer with TransferWithSeed. The purpose is to transfer from the seed account, and in order to do so we need to verify ownership with the base account and seed, which is not part of the regular TransferParams, hence the need for TransferWithSeedParams.
